# jquery.show() on multiple targets

Tags: jquery, html

I have several links (15) and also 15 DIVs with name and images.

On pageload I wan't all images hidden and whenever I click on the name's link or on the div's name, it will open up. I managed to do it on clicking on the div's name, but not with the links since there are multiple one's each with diffrent target.

```
<ul>
 <li><a href="#">Donald</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Mickey</a></li>
 (many more)
</ul>

<div class="box">
 <div id="name">Donald</div>
 <div id="name-image">
  <img src="...">
 </div>
</div>
<div class="box">
 <div id="name">Mickey</div>
 <div id="name-image">
  <img src="...">
 </div>
</div>
(many more)

$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#name-image').hide();
 $(function () {
  $('#name').click(function () {
   $(this).siblings('#name-image').slideToggle('fast')
  })
 })
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ID`s cant be same. They need to be unique.

Use classes instead.

Try:

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="name">Donald</div>
    <div class="name-image">
        <img src="...">
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.name-image').hide();       
$('.name').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('.box').find('.name-image').slideToggle('fast');
});
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/vdQw4/1)

Comment: Thanks but then how I make each <a> tag target diffrent .name-image to show?

Comment: Change `$('[id='target']').slideDown();` to `$("#"+target).slideDown();`. `ID`s can be selected like hash+name of id [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/vdQw4/4/)

Comment: Thanks @Hiral was exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

First ID of an element must be unique, so use class values to group similar elements

```
<div class="box">
 <div class="name">Donald</div>
 <div class="name-image">
  <img src="...">
 </div>
</div>
<div class="box">
 <div class="name">Mickey</div>
 <div class="name-image">
  <img src="...">
 </div>
</div>
```

then

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.name-image').hide();
    $('.name').click(function () {
        $(this).next().slideToggle('fast')
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Lzmy5/)

Comment: Thanks but then how I make each <a> tag target diffrent .name-image to show?

Comment: @Th3Alchemist assuming the order of items are the same http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Lzmy5/3/

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you change your "name" and "name-image" from `ID` to `class`.

if you want to make each `<a>` tag target different .name-image to show, you can use your `href` attribute in your `<a>` tag. To do this, you can give the target `div` an `id` like this:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#1">Donald</a></li>
<li><a href="#2">Mickey</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="box">
<div class="name">Donald</div>
<div class="name-image" id="1">
    <img src="..." />
</div>
</div>
<div class="box">
<div class="name">Mickey</div>
<div class="name-image" id="2">
    <img src="..." />
</div>
</div>
```

then the js will be like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.name-image').hide();

$('ul li a').click(function(event) {
    var imgID = $(this).attr('href');
    $(imgID).slideToggle('fast');
});

$('.name').click(function () {
    $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');
});
});
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/96g7M/)